# jQuery doesn't work after delegating domain to third-party DNS and hosting

Tags: jquery, dns, hosting

I've made a webpage for a friend and it worked just fine for some time. 
Recently he was unable to pay for hosting so webpage became unable. It lasted four months approximately. A month ago he paid for hosting BUT now it seems like jQuery isn't working...

Hosting provider said: 
"Domain [metall-sti.ru](http://www.metall-sti.ru/) was delegated to third-party DNS and was placed on third-party  hosting: domain: METALL-STI.RU. nserver: ns1.reg.ru. nserver: ns2.reg.ru.

Website works correctly with it's technical adress [metall02.mass.hc.ru](http://metall02.mass.hc.ru/) "

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try:

1. Is the jQuery.js file actually present on the new web host?
2. Is the URL correctly pointing to the file and being included in the page?
3. Are you trying out some AJAX calls via jQuery? Are the URL's still valid?